# why use c++ Typedef?

Tags: c++

My understanding of typedef is to give a declaration an alias.
Such the declaration for int will now be referred to as Integer. But why? Why would someone use typedef? What's the more advantageous reason?

```
typedef int Integer;

Integer blamo = 50;

cout << blamo << endl;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ typedef question...easy one..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664028/c-typedef-question-easy-one)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

that isn't a good example because `Integer` and `int` don't have any different meaning. But imagine something like,

```
typedef int BlamoType;
```

Now, in the future when 'blamo' becomes a 64-bit integer, you can just change this typedef, and all other code stays the same.

Another reason for typedef is to shorten type names. For example instead of

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<int> > > blamo1;
boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<int> > > blamo2;
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<int> > > > blamoList;
```

you can do:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<int> > > BlamoType;
BlamoType blamo1;
BlamoType blamo2;
std::vector<BlamoType> blamoList;
```

Comment: This is also a great example of a problem with typedefs: "in the future when 'blamo' becomes a 64-bit integer."  When my code breaks because someone changed the type I can't see without tracking down the definition.

Comment: Jay: how does this differ from changing the internals of a normal class?

Comment: @Jay isn't that the problem with any encapsulation? Are you against encapsulation?

Answer (score 11):

A reason that no-one mentioned here: to write generic code. Consider an implementation of some container like `std::vector`. It should have a type called `std::vector<T>::value_type` so anyone that writes generic code could use it:

```
template<class Container> void f(const Container &c)
{
    typename Container::value_type v = c.back();
    // ...
}
```

How can you introduce such a type into your class? The only way is a typedef:

```
// !!!EXPOSITION ONLY!!!
template<class T> class vector
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 7):

So you only have to type 
`boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::string,std::string>>`
once?

Comment: tenfour's answer is related, and better explained. typedef allows you to abstract away the details of the type, and give it a meaningful name. It's a bit like wrapping it with an interface class, but easier. A downside is type safety - two typedefs pointing to the same class are really the same thing even if you meant them to be different. You could have typedef double Time; typedef double Money; and then assign a Time to a Money.

Answer (score 4):

Another case to consider; function prototypes/pointers.  Do you want to write this every time you define a method which takes a function pointer as an argument?

```
int Search( void* key, void* array, int len, int (*someFunc)(void*, void*) )
{
    // do stuff, call passed in function, etc.
}
```

I would rather do it this way

```
typedef int (*ComparisonFunc)(void*, void*)

int Search( void* key, void* array, int len, ComparisonFunc fn )
{
    // do stuff, call passed in function, etc.
}
```

Forgive the C comparison function here, the concept is applicable in C++ as well (but you wouldn't implement generics in terms of pointers to void of course)

Answer (score 3):

[The power of 'typedef' in C++](http://advancedcppwithexamples.blogspot.com/2010/02/power-of-typedef-in-c.html) says:

> C++ allows the definition of our own
>   types based on other existing data
>   types. We can do this using the
>   keyword typedef, whose format is:
>
> typedef existing_type new_type_name ;
>
> where existing_type is a C++
>   fundamental or compound type and
>   new_type_name is the name for the new
>   type we are defining.

**For example:**

```
typedef char C;
typedef unsigned int WORD;
typedef char * pChar;
typedef char field [50];
```

[**Some more detail about typedef Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05w82thz(v=vs.80).aspx)

---

- [Benefits Of C++ typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664028/c-typedef-question-easy-one/1664225#1664225)
- [Use of typedef with Class Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988aabex(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [Typedef - Wikipedia (Brief explanation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)

Comment: 7.1.3 [dcl.typedef] says `A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type`, therefore you can not define your own type, you can just alias another type. This is an important difference, because whereas aliases can be "converted" (not even that) into other aliases that share the same definition, new types cannot converted to other types by default. The programming language D's `typedef` indeed introduces new types, and it has `alias` for what is `typedef` in C++. Real typedefs are interesting for typesafe function argument lists (think `Angle (degree(10))`, but C++'s aliases are not.

Comment: I tend to think this definition of how typedef works ends up getting confusing when you look at such things as typedefs of function pointers. Not even that, though as when you look at the definition and then look at the array typedef it doesn't look the same. When I finally realised that you write the definition as normal but use the new type name in place of the variable name and then add typedef it became a lot clearer to me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it sure isn't to make the name *more verbose*.

There are three main reasons.

One, to make the name less verbose & easier to type.  This benefit often comes in to play when dealing with classes and/or templates.  For example, if you have a `map` between a `string` and some object, using a typedef can help by reducing constructs like this:

```
for( std::map<string, MyObj>::iterator it = my_map_.begin(); it != my_map_.end(); ++it )
```

to this:

```
typedef std::map<string, MyObj> MyMap;
for( MyMap::iterator it = my_map_.begin(); it != my_map_.end(); ++it )
```

The usefulness is proportional to how often you need to declare something of type `MyObjMap`.  Just once?  Not so useful.  A thousand times?  Pretty useful.  It also helps to make code more clear & self-documenting, especially when you declare many objects of these types.

The second reason is also possibly an anti-reason.  It is done to try to get a certain level of genericity and extensibility.  This is done especially with class member types.  The idea is to make your classes more generic so that when you change the types of the members, you don't have to change the calling code.  But I mention that this can also be an anti-reason because people often think this has much more benefit than it actually does.  Think back.  How often have you *really* changes the type of a member from, say, an `__int32` to an `__int64`?  A couple times, maybe?  Is that really enough to establish a coding pattern?

A final reason is really an extension of the first, to a degree.  To provide convenient names for pointers to functions.

Comment: I have to disagree with "It also helps to make code more clear & self-documenting". When I get code that declares variables using a typedef I don't have a clue what that variable really is. "ValueType x;" is easier to type but tells me nothing about the type.

Comment: @Jay: If you need to know the underlying type, then I agree.  This isn't *always* useful.  But in many cases, if the class is well-designed, you may not need to know the underlying type.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 3 reasons why I use typedefs, most/all of which have been covered in answers already:

**- simplification:**

```
typedef int (*funcptr)(char, unsigned long);
funcptr f;  // f is a ptr to a function taking char & unsigned long, returning an int

typedef std::vector<Record> Container;
Container c;   // c is a vector of Records
```

**- encapsulation:**

```
typedef unsigned short int MY_COUNTER;
MY_COUNTER c;
```

Now if later on, I want to make `MY_COUNTER` bigger, I just change the typedef and all the counter-related code is updated (after a recompile).  Note that if I had used `unsigned short int` explicitly everywhere for the counter, I'd have to go through all files, and only change the `unsigned short int` uses for a counter; I can't just globally replace `unsigned short int` in all code because I might use it for other things besides the counter.

**- portability**

```
typedef unsigned short UINT16;
```

Now when I go to a different platform, I just map `UINT16` to something else (e.g., `unsigned long`) in one place (header file), but all my code still works (after a re-compilation).  Almost like a "type firewall" - it prevents the platform changes from spreading into changes throughout all the code.  Any developer (particularly embedded developers who are always dealing w/ code on multiple architectures & platforms) who's ever had to go through a large C or C++ codebase & change all occurrences of `int` to `short int` or whatever will relate to this.

*Note that for any recent compiler, use of* **`stdint.h`** *is often available & a better way to approach platform portability.  But I work on many systems where the compiler is older &* **`stdint.h`** *doesn't exist (or has to be created).*

---

There are plenty of other good uses for typedefs, especially as you do more work with templates, but these 3 situations are some of the most common, useful and intuitive/obvious uses (at least IMO).

Comment: Great reply, very underrated!

Answer (score 2):

C++ has a very complex type system and some types can be very complex to express. typedef reduces the amount of code necessary. Typedef also allows for a user to be insulated from type changes and finally, it allows users to conform to semi-compile-time interfaces- like defining an iterator type.

Answer (score 0):

Other examples where it would make sense could be to have a concise shorthand for a data type that was implemented as a pointer to struct, say.