# Ensure use of custom types

Tags: c++, types, typedef

Considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943484/when-does-it-make-sense-to-typedef-basic-data-types/4943517#4943517) for the benefit of `typedefs` on basic types and why they are used, is there any way to ensure that in your project you did not use a basic type and used the typedef counterparts?

Comment: I'm not sure C++ is the right language if you're wanting to enforce things like that. The programmer should have the knowledge to know which types to use in each case.

Comment: @Mark: It is not about the knowledge. It is mistakes that we want to avoid. When coding, the types are written by habit developed over years (I am sure you can relate to it) and it is relatively easy to forget that one must use `f32` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *really, absolutely* want to ban native types but allow `typedefs`, I guess you can always do something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define int please_use_stdint_typedefs_rather_than_native_types

int main()
{
    int32_t good;  // Good typedef.
    int evil;      // Evil native type.
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -c int_forbidden.c 
int_forbidden.c: In function ‘main’:
int_forbidden.c:8: error: ‘please_use_stdint_typedefs_rather_than_native_types’ undeclared (first use in this function)
int_forbidden.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
int_forbidden.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
int_forbidden.c:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘evil’
```

That said, I don't think outright banning native types is a good idea in the general case.

Comment: The `#define` can hurt *greatly* if done before a including a standard or library header, which can happen very fast.

Comment: @Xeo, indeed, that's why I put it after the only standard header I included. That's also why I put `evil` all over the place in my answer :) In short, I agree macros should almost never be used, but that particular use suits the questioner's needs and the error messages were explicit enough, so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this results in ill-formed code, even though most compilers don't mind.

Comment: I actually did something very similar. `#define int DEFAULT_TYPES_NOT_ALLOWED DEFAULT_TYPES_NOT_ALLOWED;` in which case the error messages across MS and GCC compilers is comprehensible. The problem, as pointer out by `xeo`, is, unlike in your example, if I include this in one of our header files, which is then included by several files, all of which include the header which includes this rule, is problematic when standard/3rd-party library headers are used. BUT, this can certainly be used temporarily to weed out native types in files where we don't want them to be used.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Well, the `void main()` is already ill-formed , and `int main()` wouldn't work here either. Any "idea" that breaks `int main()` is obviously doomed from the start.

Answer (score 5):

You can make these typedefs Strong Typedefs as proposed in this boost library : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp

Comment: I am not sure whether the compiler will optimize that out or not? In `debug` it is certainly going to increase overhead, correct? (since we are working on a game engine, we require decent performance in debug build as well... games usually slow down to the point that they become unplayable in debug)

Comment: It just adds a couple adaptor member. Even in debug mode, copy elisison will surely kicks in. Guess you have to test in your particular cases.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and look at the assembly. Will be very happy if it works without overhead (although compile time may increase) and select as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a typedef is just a synonym for a type and does not actually create a new type, I don't think there would be any reliable way to ensure this. You could write a script to run through the code and look for occurrences of primitive types vs. the expected typedef counterpart.